# Bootstrap Modal freeze Page while being used as a UL Listitem

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

so basically im using the code from the Bootstrap Modal example @ w3cschools.

Im trying to place it inside an unordered list. What im trying to archieve is that you click on the list item "imprint" to open up a modal showing the full imprint of my homepage. What happens is, that the whole page gets tinted and i cant click anything.

When i place the modal code somewhere else it works perfectly fine. Thanks for your time and help!

Cheers #Jekkt

Comment: Could you please provide an [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Alright thanks everyone for reading. I got the solution.

.navbar-default {z-index: 9999;} is doing the trick

Cheers #Jekkt